# How to rename mongodb field without overwriting?

Tags: mongodb

I want to rename `foo.one` to `foo.two`.

Mongodb has a way to rename fields with update $rename:

```
db.foo.update({}, { $rename: { 'one': 'two' } }, { multi: true })
```

However, the app will be running during migration, so there could be some new records created with some `two` before migration finishes, and if I understand correctly, they'd get overwritten by migration.

Is there any way to migrate without such risks?

Comment: It is not related to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the filter part of the update call to exclude documents that already have a 'two' field:

```
db.foo.update({two:{$exists:false}}, { $rename: { 'one': 'two' } }, { multi: true })
```